# How do you store your uploaded files on your server?

Tags: php, file-upload

How to store downloaded files on a server, for example in the script Download Center? In what ways do you store uploaded files? Add to that name, which create a folder? Sorry for English.

Comment: Can you tell us more details please ... ?

Comment: For example:
home/files/$date/$IdCategory_$rand_$name.gif

Comment: For example, some every thousand files make a new folder, not to store many files in one folder. So I ask that you undertake?

Comment: @user1233943: Why does it matter if there are more than one thousand files in one folder?

Comment: To search was carried out quickly. So I was wondering how to best sort and store in order to increase productivity

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [PHP: Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) from PHP.net.

```
$date = date("Ymd");
$rand = uniqid();
$uploaddir = "/home/files/{$date}/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $IdCategory . '_' . $rand . '_' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Upload did not succeed.";
}
```

Comment: For example, some every thousand files make a new folder, not to store many files in one folder. So I ask that you undertake?